# Creating Dialog from JOptionPane and working on OK_CANCEL_OPTION

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a custom dialog box that collects two strings from the user. I use OK_CANCEL_OPTION for the option type when creating the dialog. Evertyhings works except when a user clicks cancel or closes the dialog it has the same effect has clicking the OK button.

How can i handle the cancel and close events?

Heres the code I'm talking about:

```
JTextField topicTitle = new JTextField();
JTextField topicDesc = new JTextField();
Object[] message = {"Title: ", topicTitle, "Description: ", topicDesc};
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message,  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
JDialog getTopicDialog =  pane.createDialog(null, "New Topic");
getTopicDialog.setVisible(true);
```

// Do something here when OK is pressed but just dispose when cancel is pressed.

/*Note: Please Don't Suggest me the way of **JOptionPane.ShowOptionDialog(**********);** for this issue because i know that way but i need above mentioned way of doing  and setting actions for "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons.*/

Comment: please this question is about, read Oracle tutorial, search here on this forum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
...
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message,  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
JDialog getTopicDialog =  pane.createDialog(null, "New Topic");
getTopicDialog.setVisible(true);
if(null == pane.getValue()) {
    System.out.println("User closed dialog");
}
else {
    switch(((Integer)pane.getValue()).intValue()) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        System.out.println("User selected OK");
        break;
    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
        System.out.println("User selected Cancel");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("User selected " + pane.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) you can use pane.getValue() to know which button was clicked.
From documentation:

> Direct Use: To create and use an JOptionPane directly, the standard pattern is roughly as follows:
>
> ```
>      JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
>      pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
>      JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
>      dialog.show();
>      Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
>      if(selectedValue == null)
>        return CLOSED_OPTION;
>      //If there is not an array of option buttons:
>      if(options == null) {
>        if(selectedValue instanceof Integer)
>           return ((Integer)selectedValue).intValue();
>        return CLOSED_OPTION;
>      }
>      //If there is an array of option buttons:
>      for(int counter = 0, maxCounter = options.length;
>         counter < maxCounter; counter++) {
>         if(options[counter].equals(selectedValue))
>         return counter;
>      }
>      return CLOSED_OPTION;
> ```

Hope it helps,